# typing recursive class and inheritance

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import List, Optional, Tuple, Type

class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes) -> None:
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

class Element:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, attributes: Tuple[Type['Attribute'], ...], elements: Tuple['Element', ...]) -> None:
        self._name       = name
        self._elements   = elements
        self._attributes = attributes

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

    @property
    def elements(self) -> Tuple['Element', ...]:
        return self._elements

    @property
    def attributes(self) -> Tuple[Type['Attribute'], ...]:
        return self._attributes

class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, field1: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._afield1 = field1

class SubElement1(Element):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, attributes: Tuple[Type[Attribute], ...], elements: Tuple['Element', ...], field1: bytes, field2: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, attributes, elements)
        self._field1 = field1
        self._field2 = field2
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subE  = SubElement1(b'name', None, None, b'', b'')
    subA  = SubAttribute1(b'name', b'field1')
    subE2 = SubElement1(b'name', (subA,), (subE,), b'', b'')
    print(subE2.elements[0]._field1)
    print(subE2.attributes[0]._afield1)
    print(type(subE2.elements[0]))
```

I subclass the base classes Element and Attribute to add additional fields. The fields 'elements' and 'attributes' should store the derived classes objects respectively. For SubElement1 SubElement1().elements stores a tuple with SubElement1 obejcts. All works fine, but I get the following mypy errors:

```
question.py:45: error: Argument 2 to "SubElement1" has incompatible type "Tuple[SubAttribute1]"; expected "Tuple[Type[Attribute], ...]"
question.py:46: error: "Element" has no attribute "_field1"
question.py:47: error: "Type[Attribute]" has no attribute "_afield1"
```

How can I change the code to eliminate the mypy errors?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "For SubElement1 SubElement1().elements stores a tuple with SubElement1 obejcts". All your annotations are saying that `sub_element_1.elements` must be a tuple (btw, it should be `Sequence` to be more usable) of `Element` instances. Do you want to enforce that `elements` property of class `_T` returns tuple of `_T` instances?

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yes, you're right. The elements property of class SubElement1 stores a tuple of SubElement1 instances and the attributes property stores a tuple of SubAttribute1 instances and the elements property of a class SubElement2 stores a tuple of SubElement2 instances ... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite interesting, I thought that PEP646 support is slightly better.

I assume python 3.10 and most recent released version of specific checker as of now, unless explicitly specified: `mypy==0.991`; `pyre-check==0.9.17`; `pyright==1.1.281`

## Make `elements` proper

First of all, here's the (simple enough) code that resolves "elements" issue, but does not help with attributes:

```py
from typing import Generic, List, Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Type, TypeVar


_Self = TypeVar('_Self', bound='Element')


class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes) -> None:
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name


class Element:
    def __init__(self: _Self, name: bytes, attributes: tuple[Attribute, ...], elements: Sequence[_Self]) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._elements = tuple(elements)
        self._attributes = attributes

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

    @property
    def elements(self: _Self) -> Tuple[_Self, ...]:
        return self._elements

    @property
    def attributes(self) -> Tuple[Attribute, ...]:
        return self._attributes


class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, field1: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._afield1 = field1


class SubElement1(Element):
    def __init__(self: _Self, name: bytes, attributes: tuple[Attribute, ...], elements: Sequence[_Self], field1: bytes, field2: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, attributes, elements)
        self._field1 = field1
        self._field2 = field2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subE  = SubElement1(b'name', tuple(), tuple(), b'', b'')
    subA  = SubAttribute1(b'name', b'field1')
    subE2 = SubElement1(b'name', (subA,), (subE,), b'', b'')
    print(subE2.elements[0]._field1)
    print(subE2.attributes[0]._afield1)  # E: "Attribute" has no attribute "_afield1"  [attr-defined]
    print(type(subE2.elements[0]))
```

This gives one error (commented in source). [Here's playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=e6b7e4848047c83662e8bc4a00eb92e2).

In nearest future (works even on `mypy` `master` branch, but not on `0.991`) you'll be able to replace `_Self` with `from typing_extensions import Self` and skip annotating `self` argument, like this:

```
# import from typing, if python >= 3.11
from typing_extensions import Self

class Element:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, attributes: tuple[Attribute, ...], elements: Sequence[Self]) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._elements = tuple(elements)
        self._attributes = attributes
```

You can try it [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=b25fd0fe624a680199744ddd4baa03a3) - same 1 error.

## Variadic `attributes`

Now you want to preserve `attributes` types - they can be heterogeneous, thus you need [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#reference-implementation) to continue. The class becomes generic in unknown amount of variables. `pyre` and `pyright` claim to support this (`mypy` does not, the work is currently in progress). `pyre` failed to typecheck the solution below, giving a few spurious errors. `pyright` succeed (though I personally dislike it, so won't recommend switching). Pyright sandbox is unofficial and not up-to-date, and doesn't work here - copy it locally, install and run `pyright` to verify.

```py
from typing import Generic, List, Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Type, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Unpack, Self, TypeVarTuple

_Ts = TypeVarTuple('_Ts')


class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes) -> None:
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

class Element(Generic[Unpack[_Ts]]):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, attributes: tuple[Unpack[_Ts]], elements: Sequence[Self]) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._elements = tuple(elements)
        self._attributes = attributes

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

    @property
    def elements(self) -> Tuple[Self, ...]:
        return self._elements

    @property
    def attributes(self) -> Tuple[Unpack[_Ts]]:
        return self._attributes

class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, field1: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._afield1 = field1

class SubElement1(Element[Unpack[_Ts]]):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, attributes: tuple[Unpack[_Ts]], elements: Sequence[Self], field1: bytes, field2: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, attributes, elements)
        self._field1 = field1
        self._field2 = field2
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subE  = SubElement1(b'name', tuple(), tuple(), b'', b'')
    subA  = SubAttribute1(b'name', b'field1')
    subE2 = SubElement1(b'name', (subA,), (subE,), b'', b'')
    print(subE2.elements[0]._field1)
    print(subE2.attributes[0]._afield1)
    print(type(subE2.elements[0]))
```

`Pyright` says `0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations`, `pyre` errors:

```
ƛ Found 2 type errors!
t/t.py:15:14 Undefined or invalid type [11]: Annotation `Unpack` is not defined as a type.
t/t.py:15:14 Undefined or invalid type [11]: Annotation `_Ts` is not defined as a type.
```

`mypy` goes completely crazy even with experimental flags, paste into `mypy` playground if you want to look at this.

## Homogeneous `attributes`

However, if your attributes can be represented by homogeneous sequence (so that, say, `SubElement1` instances can contain only `SubAttribute1`), things are much simpler, and the generic with regular `TypeVar` is sufficient:

```py
from typing import Generic, List, Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Type, TypeVar


_Self = TypeVar('_Self', bound='Element')
_A = TypeVar('_A', bound='Attribute')


class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name: bytes) -> None:
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name


class Element(Generic[_A]):
    def __init__(self: _Self, name: bytes, attributes: Sequence[_A], elements: Sequence[_Self]) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._elements = tuple(elements)
        self._attributes = tuple(attributes)

    @property
    def name(self) -> bytes:
        return self._name

    @property
    def elements(self: _Self) -> Tuple[_Self, ...]:
        return self._elements

    @property
    def attributes(self) -> Tuple[_A, ...]:
        return self._attributes


class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, field1: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._afield1 = field1


class SubElement1(Element[SubAttribute1]):
    def __init__(self: _Self, name: bytes, attributes: Sequence[SubAttribute1], elements: Sequence[_Self], field1: bytes, field2: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, attributes, elements)
        self._field1 = field1
        self._field2 = field2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subE  = SubElement1(b'name', tuple(), tuple(), b'', b'')
    subA  = SubAttribute1(b'name', b'field1')
    subE2 = SubElement1(b'name', (subA,), (subE,), b'', b'')
    print(subE2.elements[0]._field1)
    print(subE2.attributes[0]._afield1)
    print(type(subE2.elements[0]))
```

And this [works](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.991&python=3.10&gist=641eaedbd1048ebbf6d7f89da5974bd9).

## Bonus

All the code you present is called "writing Java in Python" ([Citation](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)). You definitely do not need getters with simple attribute access, because you can always add them later. You shouldn't write dataclasses by hands - `dataclasses` standard module will do it better. So, your example really reduces to much more concise and maintainable python:

```py
from typing import Generic, Sequence, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Self
from dataclasses import dataclass


_A = TypeVar('_A', bound='Attribute')


@dataclass
class Attribute:
    name: bytes


@dataclass
class Element(Generic[_A]):
    name: bytes
    attributes: Sequence[_A]
    elements: Sequence[Self]


# OK, if you need different names in constructor signature and class dict
class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
    def __init__(self, name: bytes, field1: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._afield1 = field1
        
        
# But I'd really prefer
# @dataclass
# class SubAttribute1(Attribute):
#     field1: bytes
# And adjust calls below to use `field1` instead of `_afield1` - you try to expose it anyway

@dataclass
class SubElement1(Element[SubAttribute1]):
    field1: bytes
    field2: bytes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subE  = SubElement1(b'name', tuple(), tuple(), b'', b'')
    subA  = SubAttribute1(b'name', b'field1')
    subE2 = SubElement1(b'name', (subA,), (subE,), b'', b'')
    print(subE2.elements[0].field1)
    print(subE2.attributes[0]._afield1)
    print(type(subE2.elements[0]))
```

... and it works. Well, will work soon - currently `Self` is not fully supported in `mypy`, and checking this results in internal error (crash), [reported here by me](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14199). `Pyright` responds with no errors. UPDATE: the error is fixed on `mypy` master, and the example above typechecks.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your detailed and understandable answer!